# Woocommerce: Modify 'Popularity" sort option so it can include custom field number together with total_sales

Tags: php, wordpress, sorting, woocommerce, meta-key

I need to modify 'Popularity' sort option on the product category. By default it is sorting by 'total_sales', but I need to add numeric custom field together with 'total_sales'.

Started first sorting only by custom field under the Popularity option:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args', 'wc_add_catalog_orderby_args' );

function wc_add_catalog_orderby_args( $args ) {
    $orderby_value = isset( $_GET['orderby'] ) ? wc_clean( $_GET['orderby'] ) : apply_filters( 'woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby', get_option( 'woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby' ) );
        switch( $orderby_value ) {
            case 'popularity':
                WC()->query->remove_ordering_args(); // first remove default Popularity sort

                $args = array(
                    'meta_key' => 'my_custom_field',
                    'orderby'  => 'meta_value_num',
                    'order' => 'desc'
                    ),
                );

            break;
        }
    return $args;
}
```

And with this one sort parameter it works. But I need to sort with 2 meta keys and I tried with making a meta_query:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args', 'wc_add_catalog_orderby_args' );

function wc_add_catalog_orderby_args( $args ) {
    $orderby_value = isset( $_GET['orderby'] ) ? wc_clean( $_GET['orderby'] ) : apply_filters( 'woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby', get_option( 'woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby' ) );
        switch( $orderby_value ) {
            case 'popularity':
                WC()->query->remove_ordering_args(); // first remove default Popularity sort

                $args = array(
                    'relation' => 'OR',
                    //'relation' => 'AND',
                    'custom_field' => array(
                        'key' => 'my_custom_field',
                        'order' => 'meta_value_num'
                     ),
                     'product_total_sales' => array(
                        'key' => 'total_sales',
                        'order' => 'meta_value_num'
                     ),
                    'orderby'  => array( 
                        'my_custom_field' => 'desc', 
                        'product_total_sales' => 'desc',
                    ),
                );

            break;
        }
    return $args;
}
```

And this didn't worked. If any anyone have suggestion I would be very grateful, coffee on me